# Unable to configure retry for Spring AMQP RabbitMQ (Spring Boot 2.0.2)

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm working with a Spring Boot 2.0.2 application and I want to configure RabbitMq to retry failed messages 3 times, with an interval between each retry.

Previously on Spring Boot 1.5.1 I have successfully setup this on `application.properties`:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.initial-interval=45000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.max-attempts=3
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.multiplier=1.3
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.max-interval=80000
```

I've tried do the same on Spring Boot 2.0.2 but it doesn't work. I've read that [these properties have changed in Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Configuration-Changelog), but even after updating the properties, it still doesn't work:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.initial-interval=45000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.max-attempts=3
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.multiplier=1.3
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.max-interval=80000
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default container type is `simple`.

Use `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true` unless you decide to use the direct container type instead.

See [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#choose-container).

The DMLC was added in Spring AMQP 2.0; the boot properties were deprecated in a later 1.5.x release, switching to the `...simple...` properties in preparation for Boot 2.0.